# 1 way sync of git repo to remote without overwriting changes

Tags: git, version-control

I'm researching the best way to handle this situation

#### Location A

- Primary Master GIT Repo
- GIT-Flow development process (work on **Feature** branches, **Develop** has latest pre-release code, **Master** holds release code)
- 99% of all coding is done on this repo

#### Location B

- Nightly a copy of **Location A**'s **Develop** and **Master** branches (mirror/pushed) to this repo
- 1% of code is written here and it is specific to this repo

#### The workflow is similar to this:

**Location A** - We write a new software package, at night it is pushed out to **B**

**Location B** - The coders add some specific features that will never return to **A**

**Location A** - A new release of the software is made and pushed out to **B**

**Location B** - << What happens??  Is there a way to automatically update the underlying software without any user interaction required?  >>

The assumption is eventually we will have multiple locations (**B**,**C**,**D**, etc.) that might have custom code they need to store (but never push back)

I know there is something called a vendor branch in SVN but I'm not sure about the best git way to handle this.  My concern is if the process is too complex it will fail.

I assume using either a remote or some sort of git mirror command would be the way to go but I'm looking for some advice.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the push to always succeed, location **B**'s develop and master branches must be perfect mirrors of the ones in location **A**. Also, you never work directly on those branches in location **B**, but on vendor specific branches: `develop-vendor` and `master-vendor`, for example (those are bad names, arguably).

Even if you only intend to modify location **B**'s code once and update it automatically thereafter, you might get into a situation where pushing from location **A** to **B** would result in a merge or rebase conflict with `*-vendor` branches, so you have to take this possibility into account in your process: for example,  [some hook](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks) located in **B** may try to automatically merge `origin/master` into `master-vendor` when commits are being pushed, but would warn you if there is any problem doing so.